# Harmonise pandas MultiIndex to string when reading Excel files

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I am reading data from an Excel file into a pandas DataFrame using `read_excel()`. Unfortunately, it seems difficult to ensure the formatting of cells in Excel and so it happens that a table like this:

```
       2018                2019
          a         b         a         b
0  1.295666 -0.544973  0.845973 -0.874668
1  0.590123  0.284364 -1.482706 -0.859350
2  0.832228  0.469992  0.994865  0.480301
3  0.098671  0.198643  0.878323 -0.119761
```

...actually has surprising indices or columns:

```
df.columns

MultiIndex(levels=[[2018, 2019, '2019'], ['a', 'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 2], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

As you can see, the primary index of the last column actually has a string for 2019 and not an integer like the others.

To be on the safe side, I would like to convert all indices to `str`ing, but pandas wont let me:

```
df.columns.set_levels(df.columns.levels[0].astype(str), level=0)

ValueError: Level values must be unique: ['2018', '2019', '2019'] on level 0
```

I see two approaches to solve this:

1. Have `read_excel()` convert column headers to string or
2. Get `set_levels()` as in my example above to work.

But I can't get either to work - any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can re-create your multiple `index` for columns

```
idx=pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns.levels[0].astype(int).unique(),df.columns.levels[1]])
df.columns=idx
df.columns
MultiIndex(levels=[[2018, 2019], ['a', 'b']],
           labels=[[0, 0, 1, 1], [0, 1, 0, 1]])
```

From op better layout format

```
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([c.astype(str).unique() for c in df.columns.levels])
```

---

**Update / Caveat**

This solution *can* lead to some headache. `data.columns.codes` (formally know as `data.columns.labels`) does not necessarily come in an increasing order from `read_excel()`, e.g. `FrozenList([[3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])` can occur. When using the `.from_product()` approach here, this will cause trouble and change the order of the column names... A workaround is to save its state and write it back after the deed:

```py
old_col_codes = df.columns.codes
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([c.astype(str).unique() for c in df.columns.levels])
df.columns.set_codes(old_df_codes, inplace=True)
```

Comment: OMG. That's the fourth time in a row, you answer my nasty pandas questions... Thank you so much! Just for the record: The title suggests I want to convert to `str`, not `int`

Comment: @n1000 ah ,overloop the question , But I think this can be easily adjust ,change the astype(str)

Comment: Yes, totally works. Just mentioned it in case you wanted to modify your answer.  I ended up using a more generalised form of your answer: `df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([c.astype(str).unique() for c in df.columns.levels])`. Thanks again.

Comment: **Attention**: Turns out that this can lead to some headache, as `data.columns.codes` (formally know as `data.columns.labels`) does not necessarily come in an increasing order from `read_excel()`. One file I have will come with the following MultiIndex codes/labels: `FrozenList([[3, 3, 2, 2, 1, 1, 0, 0], [1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]])`. Using the `.from_product()` approach here, will change the order of the column names...

Comment: A workaround to the issue mentioned in my previous comment: 1. save the old original codes/labels: `old_col_codes = df.columns.codes`, 2. run the the solution as in the answer, and 3. write the order back: `df.columns.set_codes(old_df_codes, inplace=True)`. @Wen-Ben: I can edit your answer if you wish.

Comment: @n1000 yes , please also name changed :-)